# Shopify show how close to free shipping

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid, cart

I am trying to show how close someone is to free shipping using the standard timber draw cart system. The code should be checking if the customer has $30 or less and then display how much more they need to spend to achieve free shipping, and if they are over $30 state that they have achieve the free shipping threshold.

Here is my current cart code

```
<!-- /snippets/ajax-cart-template.liquid -->
{% comment %}

  This snippet provides the default handlebars.js templates for
  the ajax cart plugin. Use the raw liquid tags to keep the
  handlebar.js template tags as available hooks.

{% endcomment %}
  <script id="CartTemplate" type="text/template">

  {% raw %}
    <form action="/cart" method="post" novalidate class="cart ajaxcart">
      <div class="ajaxcart__inner">
        {{#items}}
        <div class="ajaxcart__product">
          <div class="ajaxcart row" data-line="{{line}}">

              <div class="grid__item desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-1">
                <a href="{{url}}" class="ajaxcart__product-image"><img src="{{img}}" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="desktop-8 tablet-4 mobile-2">
                <p>
                  <a href="{{url}}" class="ajaxcart__product-name">{{name}}</a>
                  {{#if variation}}
                    <span class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{variation}}</span>
                  {{/if}}
                  {{#properties}}
                    {{#each this}}
                      {{#if this}}
                        <span class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{@key}}: {{this}}</span>
                      {{/if}}
                    {{/each}}
                  {{/properties}}
                  {% endraw %}{% if settings.cart_vendor_enable %}{% raw %}
                    <span class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{ vendor }}</span>
                  {% endraw %}{% endif %}{% raw %}
                </p>
                <p><strong>{{{price}}}</strong></p>

                <div class="display-table">
                  <div class="display-table-cell">
                    <div class="ajaxcart__qty">
                      <button type="button" class="ajaxcart__qty-adjust ajaxcart__qty--minus quantity-increment" data-id="{{id}}" data-qty="{{itemMinus}}" data-line="{{line}}">
                        <span>&minus;</span>
                      </button>
                      <input type="text" name="updates[]" class="ajaxcart__qty-num" value="{{itemQty}}" min="0" data-id="{{id}}" data-line="{{line}}" aria-label="quantity" pattern="[0-9]*">
                      <button type="button" class="ajaxcart__qty-adjust ajaxcart__qty--plus quantity-increment" data-id="{{id}}" data-line="{{line}}" data-qty="{{itemAdd}}">                        
                        <span>+</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        {{/items}}

        {% endraw %}{% if settings.cart_notes_enable %}{% raw %}
          <div>
            <label for="CartSpecialInstructions">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.note' | t }}{% raw %}</label>
            <textarea name="note" class="input-full" id="CartSpecialInstructions">{{ note }}</textarea>
          </div>
        {% endraw %}{% endif %}{% raw %}
      </div>
      <div class="ajaxcart__footer row">

          <div class="desktop-half tablet-half mobile-half">
            <p><strong>{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}{% raw %}</strong></p>
          </div>
          <div class="desktop-half tablet-half mobile-half">
            <p class="text-right"><strong>{{{totalPrice}}}</strong></p>
          </div>
        <p class="text-center">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.currency_disclaimer' | t }}{% raw %}</p>
        <p class="text-center">{% endraw %}{{ section.settings.hello }}{% raw %}</p>
        <p class="text-center">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | t }}{% raw %}</p>
        <p class="text-center">
            {% endraw %}
            {% if totalPrice <= 30 %}
            You’re just {{{30 | minus: totalPrice}}} away from FREE shipping.
            {% else %}
            You've qualified for Free Shipping.
            {% endif %}
            {% raw %}
        </p>
        <button type="submit" class="cart__checkout" name="checkout">
          {% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}{% raw %} &rarr;
        </button>
        {% endraw %}{% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
          <div class="additional_checkout_buttons">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
        {% endif %}{% raw %}
      </div>
    </form>
  {% endraw %}
  </script>
  <script id="AjaxQty" type="text/template">
  {% raw %}
    <div class="ajaxcart__qty">
      <button type="button" class="ajaxcart__qty-adjust ajaxcart__qty--minus icon-fallback-text" data-id="{{id}}" data-qty="{{itemMinus}}">
        <span class="icon icon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="fallback-text">&minus;</span>
      </button>
      <input type="text" class="ajaxcart__qty-num" value="{{itemQty}}" min="0" data-id="{{id}}" aria-label="quantity" pattern="[0-9]*">
      <button type="button" class="ajaxcart__qty-adjust ajaxcart__qty--plus icon-fallback-text" data-id="{{id}}" data-qty="{{itemAdd}}">
        <span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="fallback-text">+</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  {% endraw %}
  </script>
  <script id="JsQty" type="text/template">
  {% raw %}
    <div class="js-qty">
      <button type="button" class="js-qty__adjust js-qty__adjust--minus quantity-increment" data-id="{{id}}" data-qty="{{itemMinus}}">
        <span>&minus;</span>
      </button>
      <input type="text" class="js-qty__num" value="{{itemQty}}" min="1" data-id="{{id}}" aria-label="quantity" pattern="[0-9]*" name="{{inputName}}" id="{{inputId}}">
      <button type="button" class="js-qty__adjust js-qty__adjust--plus quantity-increment" data-id="{{id}}" data-qty="{{itemAdd}}">
        <span>+</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  {% endraw %}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
        {% endraw %}
        {% if totalPrice <= 30 %}
        You’re just {{{30 | minus: totalPrice}}} away from FREE shipping.
        {% else %}
        You've qualified for Free Shipping.
        {% endif %}
        {% raw %}
```

Which is correct... if you were offering free shipping at $0.30

Shopify stores prices as integers, not floating-point-numbers - so the values in the price variables represent cents, not dollars.  If you want to compare to $30.00, you'll need to compare to `3000`, not `30`

Also, you've put your Liquid code into a Handlebars template - Liquid is rendered server-side, so the evaluation of the cart total happens before the page is served to your client.  If the shopper changes their cart total, the template does not get re-evaluated at the server level, so the message won't be dynamic.

What you should do instead is add a new variable to your template, like `{{{ shippingMessageHTML }}}`, then edit the script file that populates the template to have a variable with the same name.

Example: 
(Note: It looks like you're using Brooklyn or one of its related themes. This theme family names the function that populates that template `buildCart`, which is usually found in an asset file named `ajax-cart`, `app` or `theme`. The extension will either be `.js` or `.js.liquid`)

Find the section of code near the bottom of the function, which should look something like this:

```
// Gather all cart data and add to DOM
data = {
  items: items,
  note: cart.note,
  totalPrice: Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, settings.moneyFormat),
  totalCartDiscount: cart.total_discount === 0 ? 0 : {{ 'cart.general.savings_html' | t: savings: '[savings]' | json }}.replace('[savings]', Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_discount, settings.moneyFormat))
};
```

At the end of that `data` object, add your message HTML. Example:

```
// Gather all cart data and add to DOM
data = {
  items: items,
  note: cart.note,
  totalPrice: Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, settings.moneyFormat),
  totalCartDiscount: cart.total_discount === 0 ? 0 : {{ 'cart.general.savings_html' | t: savings: '[savings]' | json }}.replace('[savings]', Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_discount, settings.moneyFormat)), 
  //Note: we added a comma after the previous line before adding this new one
  shippingMessageHTML: cart.total_price < 3000 ? 'Want free shipping? It\'s only ' + Shopify.formatMoney(3000 - cart.total_price, settings.moneyFormat) + ' away!' : 'Yahoo! No pay-for-shipping for you!'
};
```

With that, when the data gets merged with your cart template, the most current cart total will be used in the calculation. As long as the variable you use inside the `data` object matches the name of the variable you set in the CartTemplate, you'll be good to go!

(If you're wondering what the difference between `{{ variable }}` and `{{{ variable }}}` is, the Handlebars template language interprets double-curly-braces as text and triple-curly-braces as HTML.  So if you want to put a `span` or anything into your message, use triple braces.  If your message will only ever be flat text, you can use either double or triple)

Comment: you are a life saver. this has worked perfectly. it is a slightly different theme to the one mentioned we are using 'Mr Parker' but I was able to get this to work

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: if I wanted to use the same Ajax approach to include this in my header, I assume that I dont have to change part within Ajax-cart.js.liquid but I would just need to create a new snippet to be included?

Comment: If you're talking about a banner (or similar) that shows up on page load that shows how close the shopper is to free shipping and updates accurately when the cart contents change, I would make a two-part solution.  Part 1 would be a snippet containing the HTML that you would want to display on page load.  Part 2 would be some simple code updates to your ajax-cart.js file to update that line with the new information whenever the cart changes. For your theme, I would put the code in the `updateCountPrice` function.